# How to overwrite file extracted from zip on disk?

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

The following extracts an .xls from a .zip and then saves it with a new name into a specified directory.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachmentZip(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    
    Const saveFolder = "C:\Temp\"
    Const fileFolder = "C:\Report\"
    
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim dName As Variant
        
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        dName = objAtt.DisplayName
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dName
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        oApp.NameSpace("C:\Report\").CopyHere _
               oApp.NameSpace(saveFolder & dName).Items
               Name fileFolder & "Report.xls" As fileFolder & "NewReport.xls"
               Kill saveFolder & dName
    Next
    
End Sub
```

This works once and then fails due to the file already existing. Is there a way to overwrite the existing file?

*Bonus info*

I also have the following which does the same thing but for emails that don't have a zipped extension and this on overwrites the file on disk.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttach(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    
    Const fileFolder = "C:\Report\"
    
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
        
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile fileFolder & "\" & "OldReport.csv"
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my tests, changing the `CopyHere` to

```
oApp.NameSpace("C:\Report\").CopyHere _
       oApp.NameSpace(saveFolder & dName).Items, _
       4 + 16
```

should do it.

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx), flag `4` suppresses the progress dialog and flag `16` forces "Yes to All" responses.

In older versions of Windows (as I recall), "Yes to All" was the "overwrite" response, and that seems to hold true for me.

<sup>Tested in Word 2013 VBA on Windows 8.1 Pro.  I checked this with static filenames, not with the `.Items` collection.</sup>

Comment: I am still getting a file already exists error. It almost seems like its not even getting to the point where Windows would ask to overwrite the file and instead failing in the code because it already exists.

Comment: Going off of your line of thought I commented out the section that renamed the file and then deletes the original. This correctly overwrites the file so I am able to proceed from there. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this code would even run? Application does not have a property or function named Namespace. The GetNamespace function only allows "MAPI" as its argument. No Outlook object has CopyHere method.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Like I said, I tested in Word but not Outlook, so I can't argue with you :) .  The `Shell.Application` object comes from the `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation` TLB - add it in Tools | References and you should be able to see `Folder.CopyHere` in the `Shell32` library.

Comment: Ok then, the OP does it in Outlook Object Model, which has absolutely nothing in common with the Word Object Model.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes.  Also, I should have said earlier --- `Application` in Outlook is `Outlook.Application`, which is a different interface from `Shell.Application`.  Both are listed separately under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the registry (as is `Word.Application`).